# Impresión remota con iReport

Tags: ireport

Tengo un gran problema:

**Contexto:**

Tengo una aplicación web con *primefaces 6.0* y *ireport 4.0* donde imprimo varios reportes en formato pdf, todos funcionan correctamente.

**Problema:**

Necesito que un *reporte* que se imprima directamente en la impresora (*el nombre de la impresora debo parametrizarla, ya que no es la predefinida*) del cliente, como el reporte se ejecuta en el servidor al leer las impresoras instaladas, no encuentra nada, ya que en el servidor (*Linux Red Hat*) no hay ninguna impresora instalada.

Adjunto el código que envía a la impresora predeterminada, pero no olvidar que quiero enviarla a otra impresora:

```
String ctxPath = getServletContext().getRealPath("/");
            connection = utilServiceDelegate.getDataSource()
                    .getConnection();
        HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse) FacesContext
                .getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext()
                .getResponse();

        JasperPrint jasperPrint = JasperFillManager.fillReport(ctxPath+ rutaReporte, parameters, 
                connection);

        JasperPrintManager.printReport(jasperPrint, false);
```

Si alguien ha resuelto esto con *ireport 4* o inferior, le agradecería demasiado.
Gracias.

Comment: ¿Has consultado la documentación? Por favor [edit] tu pregunta con lo que hayas intentado (código), los errores específicos puedas tener y los resultados de investigación que hayas intentado.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Logre solucionarlo.

En si no cambia nada en mi código, tuve que instalar un cliente samba en el servidor linux, y de esta manera poder ver la impresora compartida en red de windows.

De esta manera el servidor de aplicaciones puede detectar las impresoras que el
servidor tiene configuradas:

Les dejo el código para leer las impresoras que puede ver el server y enviar a imprimir a una de ellas:

```
JasperPrint jasperPrint = JasperFillManager.fillReport(ctxPath
                    +rutaReporte, parameters, connection);
JasperExportManager.exportReportToPdfFile(jasperPrint, rutaReporte);                
Document document = PDDocument.load(new File(rutaReporte));             
PrintService myPrintService = findPrintService("HP Laser 400");
PrinterJob job = PrinterJob.getPrinterJob();
job.setPageable(new PDFPageable(document));
job.setPrintService(myPrintService);
job.print();
document.close();


//funcion encontrar impresoras

private static PrintService findPrintService(String printerName) {                
  PrintService[] printServices = 
  PrintServiceLookup.lookupPrintServices(null,null);        
  for (PrintService printService : printServices) {            
    if (printService.getName().trim().equals(printerName)) {                
        return printService;
    }
  }
  return null;

}
```